# Play Services Unity Авторизация

Tags: unity3d, авторизация, google-play-services

Приветы. Подскажите, кто знает. Не могу подключить Play Services. Делаю если релизный билд, то ничего вообще не происходит, если делаю билд для отладки, то вылетает окошко о подключении к Google Games, но авторизация проваливается. Кусок скрипта прилагаю

```
void Start() {
  PlayGamesClientConfiguration config = new PlayGamesClientConfiguration.Builder().Build();
  PlayGamesPlatform.InitializeInstance(config);
  PlayGamesPlatform.DebugLogEnabled = true;
  PlayGamesPlatform.Activate();

  SignIn();
}
void SignIn() {
  Social.localUser.Authenticate(success => {
    if (success) {
      Debug.Log("log ON");
    }
    if (!success) {
      Debug.Log("log OFF");
    }
  });
}
```

Подписано все отним ключом, не которым предлагает гугл, а своим.

Answer (score 1):

Добрый день.
Столкнулся с такой же проблемой и долго не мог понять в чем дело. Потратил неделю примерно, но в итоге все решилось.
Лично у меня оказалось, что проблемы так таковой и нет. 
Я использовал ключ SHA1 из сертификата для подписи приложения. Данный ключ работает только если вы выложите приложение в Google console и запустите приложение скачав из маркета (достаточно выложить как альфа версию). 
Почему так? Если упрощенно - когда вы выкладываете приложение первый раз, гугл запрашивает подключение Google Play App Signing. 
Если вы зарегистрированы в данной программе, то подписываете приложение ключом загрузки. Google проверяет и удаляет подпись ключа загрузки, а затем подписывает приложение с помощью исходного ключа подписи. После этого оно становится доступно пользователям.  Регистрацию в программе подписания приложений Google Play нельзя отменить.
Поэтому ключ SHA1 из сертификата для подписи приложения работает только после загрузки на сервер вашего приложения и обработки его Google. Подключиться к сервисам из Build Unity в таком случае не получится

Comment: Приветствую, спасибо за внимание к теме, но к сожалению у меня не тот случай, я не подключал подпись от Гугла, а использую свой ключ.